# How can I send money to someone from India to Pakistan?

Tags: foreign-exchange, money-transfer, online-payment, paypal, inr-indian-rupee

I've one friend in Pakistan who did freelance work on a website project. So, I have to pay him for it. But unable to find any gateway.

Comment: Haven't they provided payment options? Are payment terms not a part of your commercial agreement?

Comment: He is my friend. So started work and now some work has been done. I have to release initial payment. So, I'm asking. I did not get any method to transfer payment online or offline from India to Pakistan.

Answer (score 1):

Visit any leading bank and ask them to do a swift transfer. It is expensive.